# libGDX iOS home button kills the game

Tags: ios, libgdx

I'm developing a libGDX game for Android and iOS (MobiDevelop's RoboVM fork). Android works perfectly, but I have a issue on iOS. When the iPhone home button is pressed to leave the game, and I launch the game again by tapping on icon, the game does not resume from where it was paused, but instead restarts, which means the loading screen is displayed, all assets are reloaded, and the main menu appears. Like a fresh/new start of the app. I do not have any specific configuration for the iOS module in my libgdx project and am using what was pregenerated.

Is it possible to tell iOS that I do *not* want to kill the process? I want to switch to pause/sleeping mode only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reason of this problem. I tested it on the real device, therefore I was unable to see a logs. When I switch to simulator and look at the logs, I found a **NullPointerException**. This was a cause of application crash. When I fix this bug, everything works as I expected. After iPhone home button is pressed, pause() method of com.badlogic.gdx.Screen is called and after rerun the game, it continues from exactly where it stops / pauses.

I learned a lesson: make a tests on simulator at first :-)

Comment: You can see the console of a device, too. If run from RoboVM plugin, the console of your game is displayed within the run tab. To see the console of a device at any time, open Xcode, go to Window -> Devices, select the connected device and click the Open console button

Answer (score 0):

While I am entirely unfamiliar with libGDX, I can tell you that except for a few very specific cases (VOIP etc.), you cannot control what iOS does with your app when the home button gets pressed.

Furthermore, it is the responsibility of the developer to save the app's state when the app leaves the foreground since this is not something that is or can be handled automatically in a performant way.